# Using auto layout with static background image

Tags: ios, xcode6, autolayout

I am new to auto-layout and struggling with the layout of a view.

I have a UIImage pinned to the superview (0,0,0,0), it is set to aspect to fit.

[image]

I am struggling to add labels and buttons that remain in position relative to the image as the device screen size changes

[image]

What would be best way to set these labels/buttons to change with screen size and background image? I am trying make each objects height relative to its direct parent and then leading edge of superview.

Any input appreciated

Comment: i would not recommend you way of building an ui. it would be far better to split what you are trying to achieve into a "real" background image and than add buttons which themselves have background images (the black edgy thingys...)

Comment: Does this app rotate? This might be easier to do with frame math if it doesn't. I love auto-layout if I have to deal with reorienting the interface but if you want to use it here I think you are going to have to use device dependent constants anyway. If you are really set on it I would constrain the horizontal centers of the buttons to the center of the superview and then constrain the buttons to the bottom of the superview with a negative constant that would have to be device specific. Once that is all and done, it would work, but kind of defeats the purpose when you could just use frames.

Comment: A bit beyond my capabilities with auto layout, can u recommend a good tutorial that deals with device specific constants? And no the app won't but will remain in portrait