# Resizing buttons and position on a static background image

Tags: ios, autolayout, interface-builder, swift4, xcode9

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am working to have my buttons height and position adapt to screen size changes like the pictures shown above. The buttons themselves will remain clear and only serve as a simple way to handle taps that trigger the segues to different screens. My goal is to make it so that as the image stretches across different screen sizes, I would like the buttons to keep equal height and width and position with the windows.  I know that if the windows had properties I could simply make the buttons have an equal size and width to them and be done, but as I mentioned the image is static and it has to stay that way for the time being. I've tried creating constraints for the buttons and that has only proven to be a headache and I don't know if stack views will help me here either, I know this is fairly complex, but I'm ok with that I just need some direction.

UPDATE: In an effort to follow the instructions LGP listed properly I started from step 1. As I mentioned in the comments, I believe it's simply the ratio and the constraints conflicts since when I remove one or two it works fine, but then how do I set the constraints so it fills the entire screen and maintains the ratio of the picture? Also shown are the constraint conflicts for the image view an it isn't showing the aspect ratio of the parent container view either
 [image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30088595/using-auto-layout-with-static-background-image?rq=1

I saw a similar question was asked a few years ago, the app will remain in portrait mode and while I'm not sure what frame math is, if that would help me an explanation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it in interface builder it is not too hard. You should use *spacer views* and *proportional sizes* to position the buttons. That way, whatever size your background will have, all the elements will follow.

**1. Create a container that has the same proportions as you image.** Add a regular `UIView` and set an `Aspect Ratio` constraint with a multiplier of `852:568`. This is the dimension of your background photo, 852 x 568 pixels, but the actual values don't matter, as long as the aspect ratio is the same. (Don't forget to also tie up the container view to however you want it in your view controller. See the UPDATE below on how to do this.)

**2. Place the background image in the container.** Add an image view as a child to the container. Set the constraints to touch all four edges of the container. Set the `Image` property to you image, and set `Content Mode` to `Aspect Fit`.

**3. Add the first spacer view.** Add a regular `UIView` to the container view (see leftmost, white view below) and set the constraints as follows:

- `height = 1` (not important, I used 10 in the image)
- `Top space to Superview = 90` (not important)
- `Leading space to Superview = 0`
- `Width equal to Superview` with multiplier **dw:cw** <- *This makes it proportional!*
   **dw** is the distance from the left edge to the first window/button, and **cw** is the width of the container. If your container is 375 wide, and your distance to the first button is 105, the multiplier will be 105:375.

**4. Add the second space view.** This is the vertical spacer, going from top to first button. Set it up similar as the first spacer, except make the *height* proportional to the containers height, and the width fixed.

**5. Add the first button.** Constrain its left and top edges to the spacers, then make its width and height proportional to the container.

**6. Add the remaining spacers and buttons.** They are all the same. Just remember where to make them proportional. All buttons are constraint to the single vertical spacer.

Finally, you should make the spacer views hidden. You can easily try it within your Storyboard by selecting different devices.

[image]

I chose to add everything on iPhone 8, but it is not really important. Here is what it looks like when I change to `iPad Pro 12.9"` and `iPhone SE`. Note how the buttons are positioned correctly. The spacer move around a little because they have partly fixed distances, but it works fine anyway.

[image]

[image]

---

UPDATE: Here is how to constrain the container view in the view controller's view to make the container fill the whole view and still keep its aspect ratio.

First, set the **image view's** (the one you added in step 2 above) `Content Compression Resistance Priority` to `200` for both `Horizontal` and `Vertical`. This will allow the image to compress rather then expand *if* it has a choice.

Second, Add the following constraints to you container:

- `Align Center X to Superview`
- `Align Center Y to Superview`
- `Equal Width to Superview >= 0`
- `Equal Height to Superview >= 0`
- `852:568 Ratio to View` <- *This you should already have!*

Now the container will always center on screen, it will always fill *at least* the entire screen, but will also allow it to fill beyond in both X and Y.

[image]

---

UPDATE 2: If you want to ignore the photo's aspect ratio, and always fill the screen with the photo, you just add constraints for the container view to each side to its superview. Your container view's constraints should look like this.

[image]

In step 2 you will need to set the image's `Content Mode` to `Scale to fill`. The rest should be the same.

Comment: This is a very good answer and I think it will be helpful, but please forgive me i have some questions that i'll go in order of asking.

for the first part, How did you get the view controller that contains the UIView with the aspect ratio that has the multiplier set to the dimensions of the photo? I would share a photo of what it looks like on my end, but the view controller does have the same proportions of the UIView. also does 'tying up the container to however you want it in the view mean adding the appropriate constraints? I apologize if these are rudimentary questions.

Comment: Not sure I understand your first question right, but the view controller usually (or more precisely, its _view_) fills the screen, so has the size of the screen. How would you like the image to be laid out on the screen? Your second question, yes! If you tell me how you want the layout of the image on different screen sizes, I will try to help if needed.

Comment: Sorry that I wasn't clear with my first question. In your first image after you added the container view to the view controller and add the aspect ration constraint it looks like the screen size changed to fit the aspect ratio. but when I tried to follow the instructions, the constraints are set but the image goes off the screen because the aspect ratio is so big. I should mention the image I have up above is just an example and I cant so the actual one because it's for the company I work for. The image will have an Aspect Fill for it's content mode.

Comment: So how would you like the image to layout on the screen?
My positioning of the container view is just an example, as I don't quite know how you would like it.

Comment: Oh I see, I want the image to fill the entire screen. It will be the first screen users see when they log in.

Comment: Ok, after doing some studying on my own I feel like I have a better understanding of what's happening here. That being said, I am facing some confusion. When i gave the container view it's aspect ratio, I brought up errors because of constraints of how I set the container up in the view controller, When I removed the leading and trailer constraints the image moves out of the view controller, but it looks ok. How do i get it so that I can have the image show up in the view controller properly like yours and move to adding the spacers?

Comment: @AdamBrashear I have updated my solution to explain how you can set up the container view to fill the entire screen.

Comment: I followed the instructions that you mentioned in your edit and it works fine! however when i move in the smaller screen sizes the image doesn't shrink but maybe it isn't supposed to, I just wanted to mention that to be entirely sure.

Comment: It is supposed to shrink to either have exactly the same height as the screen or the same width as the screen. If not, please check that you did steps 1 and 2 above, and that you set `Content Compression Resistance Priority` on the image view as described in my update.

Comment: I am starting from the beginning, I'm going to edit my question so that I can show where I'm having the issue. For step one I cant constrain all four sides of the UIView and give it the appropriate aspect ratio without it throwing an error. I think it's do to the constraints conflicting with the ratio.

Comment: Oh, I think I understand what's your problem. You should forget my _comments_ here on how to set up the container. The **update** I did to the solution contains _all_ constraints you should need to set up the container as you want it. You should only have those five constraints in the very last image.

Comment: I just first want to say thank you so much for being patient with me and still helping me with this, I went ahead and change the container constraints to match your update and I finally get what is supposed to happen.I'm still getting conflicts though with the container being equal to the width and height of the view controller and trying to maintain the aspect ratio at the same time. Did I do something wrong again? I updated my question with photos to show where I'm at now.

Comment: You are welcome! I can see one vital difference. You need to change the width and height constraints from `=` to `>=`. Bear in mind that depending on which view is on the left side and on the right side, you should set it so that the _container's_ width and height is `>=` to its superviews width and height.

Comment: I am officially showing all blue!! I made another edit to show it too! I'm happy to have finally had that sorted out, is there a reason the image hasn't adjusted to fit the entire screen on it's own or do I have to continue with the steps in order to make that happen, I just want to make sure I have done this right before moving on to the spacers.

Comment: Good! As far as I can see the image fills up the screen. It is aligning with the top and bottom and continues beyond left and right. Was this not what you wanted?

Comment: For the image I used as an example here, that was fine. I tried the same example with the image I'm actually using and because the aspect ratio continues beyond the view controller the image zooms in too much. Is it possible to achieve the same spacer view effect with the image constrained to the margins of the screen? that's more so what I need, I'll show an edit in my question again

Comment: I updated the photo to better show what I'm after. I'd like to display the entire picture (in my case the entire building) but still have it properly fill the screen at any time and still add the spacer views.

Comment: Oh, I see. Then you just reverse the two `>=` to `<=` on the container view, and restore the image view's `Content Compression Resistance Priority` to `750`. This will always fit the entire image on the screen with extra space on _either_ left/right or top/bottom sides.

Comment: I understand more now, after playing with it yesterday the constraints that I need for my actual building are the height and width being equal to the super view, but I, of course, get conflicts due to the from these and the height and width. Is there a way to fix this because if I can make it work it'll be what I need and then I can move to the spacers. I'll include a picture so you can see the constraints

Comment: The last picture is similar to what I'm going for. I realize this wasn't the best building photo due to its size and I'll choose a better one going forward.

Comment: So what you really want is that the photo be compressed? Don't you want the correct aspect ratio on the photo?

Comment: My apologies for the confusion, I changed the photo so it makes more sense what I'm going for, the new photo is almost identical to the one I'm actually using. I want to get the whole scene like the picture on the left, but I want it to have the right aspect ratio like the one on the right that has the aspect fit content mode. I just need the whole photo to show.Is this possible?

Comment: In your original answer your photos show the entire image properly and it keeps it's aspect ratio. That's what I would like.

Comment: Well, to be honest, no. Any photo has a given size and aspect ratio. While you can resize a photo for different devices, you can't change the photos aspect to fit different devices aspect ratios without distorting the photo and compressing it in either direction.

Comment: You need to decide to either keep the aspect ratio, in which case the the photo will be cropped (cut smaller) from top/bottom or left/right depending on the device. Or you can freely resize the photo to fit the device, but then you will lose the original aspect ratio on at least some devices, and instead have compression in one direction.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. I'm fine with some compression so then how would I proceed with adding the spacer views in that regard? apologies again for the confusion, I should have specified this from the start.

Comment: I added the spacers properly and the first button and everything is working fine so far, only thing is that the button moves when i move the screen sizes up. I will put an example up above but do I have to further adjust the height of the button proportional to the container that keeps it at the window even when the screen gets larger?

Comment: It should work even with compressing photos. I can confirm it tomorrow on my other computer.

Comment: Ok I put up the new photos to show what was happening, I noticed that the button stays where it's supposed to but the button's height doesnt stretch as the window 'grows longer'

Comment: It looks like your the top of the vertical spacer doesn't go all the way up. Perhaps you attached it to a margin? In any case it should be attached to `superview` top `= 0`.

Comment: I changed the top constant of the vertical spacer, but am still facing the same issue as before once i move the screen to a pad size. do I need to change a constraint or proportional constraint on the button too? I changed the top space from the spacer, but it simply made the button move too far down once I moved to a smaller screen size.

Comment: Did you make the vertical spacer (step 4) proportional to the superview's **height**?

Comment: I believe i did it the right way yes. Does the issue have to do with the content mode or should the button stretch properly one the spacers height is set up properly no matter what?

Comment: The button will stretch properly if it is set up properly, having width and height proportional to its superview. The propblem is with the vertical spacer. The only place the content mode matters is for the image view, it must be `scale to fill`. I have confirmed this on my test file. I can switch between portrait and landscape, and it adjusts fine.

Comment: I will work on fixing be vertical spacer then. For the DW:CW for the height is the DW the distance from the top of the container to the top of the button? I think I have the CW down fine.

Comment: Yes, it is!! - -

Comment: SUCCESS!! I fixed my constraints and now have a clear understanding of how to make this work for my actual background. Thank you so very much for you help and most of all for your patience and kindness! Hopefully I can return the favor someday!

Comment: Excellent! Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

Use **percentage based positions and size**. Identify the positions of windows in percentage basis, and create the origin in x and y dimension by multiplying the percentage to the width and height of the screen. I am assuming that you are using **ScaleToFill** as content mode of the ImageView.

Similarly for calculating size, identify the width and height of the ImageView on percentage basis, and multiply the values in percent with the total width and height of the screen.

For example, to calculate the position of Window one-

**Suppose, window1.x** in percentage basis is 25% & total image view width is 400 (for example), than window1.x pixel position will be-

```
window1X = (25 * 400) / 100 = 100
```

**Suppose, window1.y** in percentage basis is 25% & total image view height is 300 (for example), than window1.y pixel position will be-

```
window1Y = (25 * 300) / 100 = 75
```

**Suppose, width** is 7% of image views width, than width in pixel will be -

```
window1Width = (7 * 400) /100 = 28
```

**Suppose, height** is 12% of image views height, than height in pixel will be -

```
window1Height = (12 * 300) /100 = 36

window1.frame = CGRectMake (window1X, window1Y, window1Width, window1Height)
```

Same approach for other windows, to calculate their positions(size will be same as window 1)

This approach will work across all screen resolutions, since it uses **percentage based calculations** & **ScaleToFill** as content mode for image view.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I hadnt thought to look at it that way. This approach will also account for when the image changes size, to an iPad 9.7in for example? Also how does the approach change is I'm using Aspect Fill in the content mode? I would just like to have a better view of the bigger picture in all this.

Comment: I should also mention that I'm doing this in interface builder and not in code